# the music of the planetary spheres

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is "around which orbited the music of the planetary spheres" a poetic interpretation? Can anyone explain it a little? It is talking about Pythagorean philosophy.

I think it means that the idea of mathematics being at the heart of music brought about the belief that the earth was also at the center of the world. Am I right?

Context:

"That there were numerical relations in music was only evidence that the earth was at the centre of a harmonious universe, around which orbited the music
of the planetary spheres."

Comment: I wouldn't have said that the music orbits the fixed earth, but rather that the spheres within which the orbiting planets move produce the harmony referred to as the music of the spheres or [_musica universalis_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musica_universalis).

Answer (score 1):

As rogermue points out, the ancient Greeks thought that heavenly bodies -- the sun, the moon, and the visible planets -- orbited the Earth in circular paths, which would place them on abstract spheres surrounding the Earth.  Pythagoras recognized that the earthly harmonies of musical tones from strings were governed by the proportions of the lengths of those strings, so he proposed a heavenly (i.e., celestial) music generated by the orbiting bodies and based on the proportions of the radii of their spheres.  This became known as Musica Universalis, the music of the universe or music of the spheres.  This "music" isn't audible, but the vibrations were thought to influence life on Earth.  Plato in *The Republic* basically says that the eyes are to astronomy as the ears are to music.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musica_universalis) has a good introduction.

Note that this "music" for the ancients was not merely a figure of speech, but actual harmonies beyond our human senses to discern directly.

The analogy with music explained the relationships of the placements of the heavenly bodies, not the fact that they orbited the Earth, which was determined by astronomical observation.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to an old view of the solar system with the earth as the centre and seven spheres for the various planets. I don't know how the music comes into in this model and would have to do some research. In literature poets like Goethe in Faust speak of the music of spheres (Sphärenklänge). You are right this model of the cosmos and the idea of music dates back to the Pythagorean school.

Here's a long treatise about this topic  [Link](http://www.sacred-texts.com/eso/sta/sta19.htm)

Here's another link https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/math5.geometry/unit3/unit3.html